# How to cancel Magento order programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, php, orders, programmatically

I want to change the order status to 'canceled' when payment failed.
I've tried the code below but the order status gets saved as processing:

```
        $orderId = $number8; //order id
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId); //load order
        $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true)->save();
        $state = 'canceled';
        $status = $state;
        $comment = "Changing state to $state and status to $status Status";
        $isCustomerNotified = false; //whether customer to be notified
        $order->setState($state, $status, $comment, $isCustomerNotified);
        $order->addStatusHistoryComment("Payment Failed",
            Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED);
        $order->setStatus($status);    
       $order->save();


        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')->addError(Mage::helper('checkout')->__($errorMessage));
        $this->renderLayout();
```

Please assist.
I have a condition in my model if(payment fails) execute code above but the order gets saved as processing instead of canceled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use only following lines of code no need to save order again & aganin:

```
$orderId = $number8; //order id
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$order->cancel()->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, 'canceled', 'Payment Failed', false)->save();
```

Second last argument is commnet & Last boolean parameter is $isCustomerNotified false in your case.

What ever payment method you are using it should have cancelAction in it you need to write following code in it:

```
public function cancelAction()
    {
        $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('orderId');
        if ($orderId) {
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
            if ($order->getId()) {
                // Flag the order as 'cancelled' and save it
                $order->cancel()->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, 'canceled', 'Gateway has declined the payment.')->save();
                Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('onestepcheckout/index/index/cc/back', array('_secure' => true));
            }
        }
    }
```

In my case I have this redirect path

onestepcheckout/index/index/cc/back

Put yours

Comment: @radhiyah williams please let me know if you still have an issue?

Comment: i tried that code and it  is still saves the order as processing @Hassan Ali Shahzad

Comment: in my payment setup new order status is set to processing but thats for when its successful. i have a if statement that checks if it failed if it did i want to change the status to canceled but nothing working

Comment: ok debug by the following ways:
1) First you confirm you have 'canceled' status present in in admin, if not add plz.

2) Second If present then Second add exit(); after the above save line and see 
 the status. If upto here its working fine, then in this case need to debug deep their must be some code which is changing order status back to processing.

Comment: @RadhiyahWilliams Update ?

Comment: does exactly the same thing, on the admin side of payment method i have list of all the statuses'processing,canceled, hold etc' the exit(); does nothing but the order will be saved automatically as processing as the one its set to on the admin side

Comment: Its mean that your above code is not called. you are in wrong file update your complete code and from where you are think it should be called.

Comment: my code is in the model method called getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl i have a if statement here to check if success or not and if not run the cancel order code

Comment: Oh Man, your direction is not correct: function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl will return you only redirect url. dont do any thing in this function.

Comment: which payment method you are using?

Comment: I had updated question now check

Comment: ive created my own payment method and used this method to post to my API it works perfectly just when the API returns a error the code to set the order status to cancel does not work

Comment: I had also created my own payment method but I had follow stander-eds and I have cancelAction in it I also have same scenario in which If payment error I mark order canceled.

Comment: the cancelAction method i can place in the model and call it in the if statement? or must it be in a different file?

Comment: you definitely have one function in which your response return after online payment.
In this function you need to verify response if have error sttus redirect to cancelAction else redirect to success action.
like following:

if (isset($response['errors']) || $response['status'] == 'Declined') {
                $this->_redirect('yourRouter/YourPaymentController/cancel', array('_query' => $params));
            } else {
                $this->_redirect('yourRouter/YourPaymentController/success', array('_query' => $params));
            }

Comment: cancelAction will be posted above.

Comment: @RadhiyahWilliams Now you should accept this as answer

Comment: i have accepted but hasnt helped me, maybe will help someone else. Thanx for assisting tho

Comment: OMG where you stuck now ?

Comment: im new to magento and ive developed this payment method it works everything fine up until a point now where i just need to have the order saved as canceled when the API returns a failed error. so in the model i have If(apiresponse =='Declined){// need code here to cancel the code}' i tried redirecting to the controller cancel method but no luck

Comment: Its not possible. On redirect have you verify it lands in proper cancelAction ?
You are new to magento but not new to development you had developed module at-least you have an idea where request id routing. Its to much simple.thing.

Comment: else if($tranactionSuccess == "Declined")
        {   $this->_redirect('accountpayment/PaymentController/cancel', array('_query' => $orderId));
       }

Comment: Thats what i added in the method to redirect to the controller

Comment: have you verify api response in case of rejection is "Declined"?
Also following route is not correct:


$this->_redirect('accountpayment/PaymentController/cancel', array('_query' => $orderId)); }

should not include Controller with class name in route.

Comment: yes i have im nw checking if API says declined then redirect to cancel action